# Pinging a Node.js server from PHP on AWS

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a long procedure I have written in node.js, but I'd like the PHP side of my application control kicking it off. My node is something like:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log('Got request')

  try{
    doProcedure()
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('Really bad error while trying to do the procedure:')
    console.error(e.stack ? e.stack : e)
  }

}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
```

When I run this on my local machine, http://localhost:8124 will trigger things correctly. On aws, I've added the 8124 port but requests to mydomain.com:8124 aren't picked up by node.

[image: Port settings in AWS]

I tried stopping httpd and then letting node listen on port 80, to rule out ports not being forwarded correctly, but it still saw nothing.

So two questions, I guess:

1. **How to get Node listening as a daemon, so I can pass over requests?** ("update user x", "update user y", "update all users", etc)
2. **How do I ping that daemon from php to start these procedures in an AWS evironment?**

Bonus question: Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Thanks all,
~Jordan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you omit the second argument to listen(), node will listen on all IP addresses.  That way you can run the same code locally to test and also on your EC2 instance.

In your catch block, you might also want to send back an HTTP error response to the client.

Comment: The client isn't viewing anything, it's simply an HTTP touch that I'm issuing from php on the same machine to start the procedure.

Comment: Ding ding ding! Omitting the IP got things working, and is a sweet local/production trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you should have a 10.* ip iirc for aws, your elastic/dynamic ip cant be bound to

Comment: I was under the impression that my elastic IP is the IP that my domain connects to, and the IP that any webserver should be listening on. where would this 10.* ip be found?

Comment: Omitting the IP to listen on makes the server listen on all IP's and works perfectly.

Comment: /sbin/ifconfig -a, on my EC2 instance i have a 10.* IP and i have an elastic external IP that i use to connect to. the ext ip isn't actually bound to the server, it's like port-forwarded 1:1 nat or something

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using your server's IP address (instead of 127.0.0.1) in the createServer.listen() call?

Comment: Listening on 50.17.254.0:8124 gives me the error:  

"Error: EADDRNOTAVAIL, Cannot assign requested address"